# Proxy Route Strings

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I'm trying to make a JS Proxy that does this.

```js
routes.api.posts => '/api/posts'
routes.api.posts('postId') => '/api/posts/postId'
routes.api.posts('postId', { name: 'alex' }) => '/api/posts/postId?name=alex'
routes.api.posts({ name: 'alex' }) => '/api/posts?name=alex'
```

I've referenced these

- [How do I trap arguments to a target method when using a Proxy object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25069023/how-do-i-trap-arguments-to-a-target-method-when-using-a-proxy-object)
- [Determining if get handler in Proxy object is handling a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441259/determining-if-get-handler-in-proxy-object-is-handling-a-function-call)

I've gotten this far.

```js
var obj = {
  func: undefined,
  realFunc: (args) => args,
  prop: undefined,
  realProp: true
};

var handlers = {
  path: '',
  get: (target, name) => {
    const prop = target[name];
    if (prop != null) { return prop; }

    let isProp = true;
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      handlers.path = `${handlers.path}/${name}`
      console.log('handlers.path', handlers.path)
      if (isProp) {
        console.log(`props ${name}`)
      } else {
        // it's a function
        console.log(`props ${name}`)
      }
    });
    return new Proxy(() => {}, {
      get: handlers.get,
      apply: (a, b) => {
        isProp = false;
        return new Proxy(() => {}, handlers);
      }
    });
  }
};

var routes = new Proxy(obj, handlers)

var case1 = routes.api.posts
console.log(`routes.api.posts()`, case1 === '/api/posts', case1)

var case2 = routes.api.posts('postId')
console.log(`routes.api.posts('postId')`, case2 === '/api/posts/postId', case2)

var case3 = routes.api.posts('postId', { name: 'alex' })
console.log(`routes.api.posts('postId'`, case3 === '/api/posts/postId?name=alex', case3)

var case4 = routes.api.posts({ name: 'alex' })
console.log(`routes.api.posts({ name: 'alex' })`, case4 === '/api/posts?name=alex', case4)
```

Comment: Why `Promise.resolve`? Absolutely do not do that, there's nothing asynchronous in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work well. `get` intercepts missing props and creates new `routes` objects on the fly, while `apply` takes care of function calls.

```js
let makeRoutes = (prefix = '') => new Proxy(() => {}, {
    get(target, prop) {
        if (prop === 'toString')
            return () => prefix
        if (prop in target || typeof prop !== 'string')
            return target[prop]
        return makeRoutes(prefix + '/' + prop)
    },

    apply(target, thisArg, args) {
        let url = prefix
        for (let a of args)
            url += typeof a === 'object'
                ? '?' + new URLSearchParams(a)
                : '/' + a
        return url
    },
})


let routes = makeRoutes()

console.log('' + routes.api.posts)
console.log('' + routes.api.posts('postId'))
console.log('' + routes.api.posts('postId', {name: 'alex'}))
console.log('' + routes.api.posts({name: 'alex'}))

console.log('' + routes.this.should.work.too('param', {name: 'alex'}))
```

Comment: You shouldn't need an `apply` trap. Simply put that code in the function itself.

Comment: @Bergi how would you make it so `routes.api.posts` doesn't return a proxy?

Comment: @AlexCory It still should return a proxy. But one with only a `get` trap: `return new Proxy((path, query) => { return prefix + … }, {get(target, key) { … }})`